# MySQL Table Update with PHP HTML Form isn't Working

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I am trying to update mySQL table using a form with PHP. Currently I have all the code set up but when I am updating my table data, age, it sets all the ages in the table to '0'. I am not sure why but any guidance would be strongly appreciated. Thanks.

Kelsey

```
<?php
    $hostname = "---------";//host name
    $dbname = "-------";//database name
    $username = "-------------";//username you use to login to php my admin
    $password = "--------";//password you use to login

    //CONNECTION OBJECT
    //This Keeps the Connection to the Databade
    $conn = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Can not connect to database')      
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$id=$_GET['FirstName'];

//Create a query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
//submit the query and capture the result
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$query=getenv(QUERY_STRING);
parse_str($query);
?>
<h2>Update Record <?php echo $sql;?></h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php


    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td>age:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Age" value="<?php echo $row['Age']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Update the Record" NAME="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php   }
    ?>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked

    $sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age='".$_POST['Age']."'";
    $conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
    }
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about the comments.

Comment: It looks like you're using PDO, which is good, but you're not using [prepared statements](http://ca1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) and have created a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).  **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in a query.

Comment: When I update any age other than the one at the very bottom and I refresh the page afterwards it still keeps the age unupdated but instead resets the very bottom age back to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good way to add the POST inside the statement itself.

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked

$age = $_POST['Age'];

$sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age='".$age."' WHERE firstname ='".$id."'";
$conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
}
?>
```

Your page is confusing. You didn't even output the result correctly. Try this:

```
<?php
$hostname = "---------";//host name
$dbname = "-------";//database name
$username = "-------------";//username you use to login to php my admin
$password = "--------";//password you use to login

//CONNECTION OBJECT
//This Keeps the Connection to the Databade
$conn = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Can not connect to database')      
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

//$id=$_GET['FirstName'];

//Create a query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
//submit the query and capture the result
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$query=getenv(QUERY_STRING);
parse_str($query);
?>
<h2>Update Record <?php echo $sql;?></h2>
<form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<?php


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td>Age:</td>
<td><?php echo $row['Age'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['FirstName'];?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Age"></td>
<td><input type=hidden" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $row['FirstName'];?>"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Update the Record" NAME="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php   }
?>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked
$age = $_POST['Age'];
$id = $_POST['firstName'];

$sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age='".$age."' WHERE firstname ='".$id."'";
$conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work... I am so lost. I have the columns in my table as FirstName LastName and Age... I go to my webpage at http://thetotempole.ca/phptester/editpage.php and type something in and nothings updated, it also says cannot update.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that this is the entire code for your page. You used $id = $_GET['firstname']; Where did you get it from?

Comment: Okay, I implemented the updated code and it is no longer giving me errors, it is just not updating the ages. I got that from another code source that I was trying to base mine off of. FirstName is one of my columns for my table. So I guess I was trying to distinguish each input by their first name.

Comment: Okay, hang on a moment.

Comment: How do i make it so WHERE FirstName is = to the row of the age input you are editing? Okay, take your time.

Comment: I put in your code @charlesisjan and my page is still not updating. I appreciate your help vastly. I am so frustrated. Maybe you can take a look at my updated page. Thank you, charles.

Comment: I actually changed a part of the table from $row[0]; and $row[2]. Check it out. I want to see if it's actually outputting data onto your page. Also, add the enctype='multipart/form-data' into your form tag so it looks like <form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Comment: It is outputting data onto my page. It is still not updating, though. Cheers

Comment: The Age column is an integer(11). Would that have anything to do with my input type?

Comment: can you add this code after the <td><?php echo $row['Age']?></td>?

:::

    <td><?php echo $row['FirstName'];?></td>

Comment: Okay, so now we know that data exists. The statement should be working, Try adding an extra > to close the tab of the hidden text. I don't think it was closed.

<td><input type=hidden" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $row['FirstName'];?>" /></td>

Comment: Looks like the last row is now updating.

Comment: It is updating, but only the one at the very bottom is working. When I update a different Age it resets the very bottom age back to 0.

Comment: When you update one, you have to refresh it because once you click the button and it updates, all values are set to 0. Or you can do a redirect to refresh the page so that all rows have the value they all need.

Comment: When I update any age other than the one at the very bottom and I refresh the page afterwards it still keeps the age unupdated but instead resets the very bottom age back to zero. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

The `UPDATE` query as its written right now updates the entire `Persons` table, not an individual record.

`UPDATE Persons SET Age=15 WHERE id = 5` will only update one record as apposed to the entire table's values.

Also, it's not good (aka *massive* security risk) to put raw post values directly into an SQL string. You should always sanity check your values before putting them into a database query.

Comment: Thank you but it is still saying it cannot update. Although when I put in your code it changed the zeros to 43's. Strange.